# Php tumblr api situation

Tags: php

```
<?
$jsonString = '{"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"blog":


{"title":"happiness.","posts":12215,"name":"random","url":"http:\/\/www.demo.com\/","updated":1354380368,"description":"","ask":true,"ask_anon":true,"share_likes":true,"likes":166 1}}}';
    $jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);
    $result = '';
    foreach ($jsonObject->response as $blog) {
    $result .= $blog->title . ' - ' . $blog->url . '<br/>' . "\n";
    }
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Since $blog->url . returns a url, how can I put this url in an anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with the anchor tag, calling [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to ensure URL characters are properly encoded:

```
$result .= $blog->title . ' - <a href="' . urlencode( $blog->url) . '">' . $blog->title . '</a><br/>' . "\n";
```